# Serial com issue with virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port

I have an issue in using the serial port with virtual box.

My host system is Windows, my guest system is ubuntu.

I have setup a serial connection between the local Windows and another distant PC, and it worked fine.

I have mapped the physical port in the virtual machine (using vbox serial port setting)

I was able to send the data from ubuntu to the distant PC, however I cannot receive data.

what is the problem?

Serial com config:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a serial to usb adapter, then you can map the usb port in virtual box instead of mapping the serial port.
And you can access the port from linux with /dev/ttyUSB where x is a number.